# Ignore condition in initial run of while loop

Tags: iteration

In C# you can write a while-loop like this

```
do {
  stuff();
} while (condition)
```

which means it will first do `stuff()` once, and only then start checking the `condition` for additional runs.

Is there an equivalent pattern in Emacs Lisp?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```el
(while (progn
         (stuff)
         (condition)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by phils is probably best. For completeness' sake, here's another pattern.

```
(let ((more t))
  (while more
    (stuff)
    (setq more (condition))))
```